# Can you share manifestEntries in Maven?

Tags: maven, manifest, packaging, maven-war-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

In my master POM, I have `<pluginManagement>` where I define configurations for the `maven-jar-plugin`,  `maven-war-plugin` and `maven-ear-plugin`.  Each of these has

```xml
<configuration>
  <archive>
    <manifestEntries>
      <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
      <SCM-Revision>${scmRevision}</SCM-Revision>
      <SCM-Branch>${scmBranch}</SCM-Branch>
      <Built-By>${user.name}</Built-By>
    </manifestEntries>
  </archive>
</configuration>
```

Is there a way to share a group of manifest entries so I don't have to add new items to 3 separate places?

Comment: Well, the best you can get, I guess, is have it in some file in your project and pass it as `<manifestFile>` configuration parameter to these plugins.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov Sounds pretty reasonable, why not post an answer?

Comment: @DuncanJones I was hoping to hear from the OP but since this might be useful for someone else, I did post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

1. Create single manifest file with necessary content and property placeholders, and place it into `src/main/resources`.
2. Have `maven-resources-plugin` process this file and generate manifest with actual property values.
3. Provide jar, war and ear plugins with link to this file.

Here's a sample configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <archive>
    <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/manifest.file</manifestFile>
  </archive>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this support each individual jar, war, etc being able to add to the manifest?

Comment: @Snekse Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Would adding a manifestFile element in the POM still allow me to separately customize each archive, such as adding `classpath` entries to the EAR and hand edited URL entries.  So basically can I concat manifestEntries + manifestFile into a new manifest.mf?  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Snekse No, I don't think that it's possible.